# Reference the variable in expression for Angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table that I'm populating from a database using ng-repeat to produce objects that will be capable of being dragged and dropped. When I drag and drop an object onto a cell I need a way to find the id that comes from the initial load from the database so that I can update the database with the new position of the object within the table. From my understanding you should be able to reference the variable in the ng-repeat expression to do this? For example:
you could reference the x in: x in names? This is just example code of a table using ng-repeat:

```
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

       <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
           </tr>
      </table>

   </div>

<script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
         $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
         .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    });
</script>
```

I have tried to find an answer for this, by trying to just use Javascript to reference elements produced by angular, but that doesn't seem to work as they are not written to the html source (unless I inspect elements, but that doesn't show my id's). I also thought I could just reference `this` from the `scope`, but it would appear each instance of x would get its own scope variable. Is there any way to do something like this within angular context or would you need to use something like jquery?

Comment: I would start by creating a directive element. You could then keep the information in the directive and also use angular.element to get DOM objects. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this would help. I'm trying to get the value of x from x in names. I'm thinking I need to understand better how data is reloaded after an element is dragged and dropped and recompiled. Maybe I don't need x from x in names, but just a simple method of capturing changes that occurred on the page and to what ID it occurred to? To do that I would still need to know exactly where to reference data from a drag and drop after page has loaded. Either as json or some other way. Does that make sense?